# I tried to optimize my PG. The results are decent. Did I do wrong somewhere? Can I do better?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have a PG database with around 1B rows. I run queries to see how good is the performance. most of the queries` execution time is subsecond, but the round trip takes much more.

I'm looking to see if there are any more optimizations I can do to my database and infra to increase the query speed.

Infra:

- RDS, instance type `db.m5.2xlarge`. It's `8 vCPU` and `32GB ram`.
- `PG 14.4`
- Storage `4TB`
- `10k IOPS`

The table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE metrics (
    id UUID,
    user_id UUID,
    entity1 UUID,
    entity2 UUID,
    entity3 UUID,
    entity4 UUID,
    start_time TIMESTAMPTZ,
    end_time TIMESTAMPTZ,
    metric_1
    ...
    metric_50
    list_1 integer[],
    list_2 integer[],
    list_3 integer[]
)
PARTITION BY LIST (user_id);
```

For every `user_id` I have a partition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE metrics_user_[user_id]
PARTITION OF metrics 
FOR VALUES IN ('[user_id]')
PARTITION BY LIST (entity1);
```

And for every `entity1` I have a subpartition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE metrics_user_[user_id]_entity1_[entity1]
PARTITION OF metrics_user_[user_id]
FOR VALUES IN ('[entity1]')
```

I have an index on the `metrics` table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX metrics_default_filters
ON metrics(entity2, entity3, entity4, start_time, end_time);
```

I run the query: (this is a typical query I'll normally use)

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT SUM([metric_x])
FROM metrics
WHERE user_id = '[user_id]'
AND entity1 = '[entity1]'
AND entity2 = '[entity2]'
AND entity3 = '[entity3]'
AND entity4 = '[entity4]'
AND start_time >= now() - interval 'x hours'
AND end_time < now() - interval 'y hours'
```

I randomize all of the values.

I get this result:

```sql
Aggregate  (cost=5956.19..5956.20 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=748.313..748.314 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2 read=1595
  I/O Timings: read=743.997
  ->  Index Scan using metrics_user_c8f0193b_c_entity2_entity3_entity4_idx on metrics_user_c8f0193b_c_entity1_4bb9c1a0_d metrics  (cost=0.57..5951.98 rows=1681 width=4) (actual time=1.337..748.100 rows=1573 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((entity2 = '9311744c-3746-3502-84c9-d06e8b5ea2d6'::uuid) AND (entity3 = '77d8a03c-8ec8-3d73-be30-60cc1d67fa4e'::uuid) AND (entity4 = '0a25865b-970a-3281-b8de-aac852124754'::uuid) AND (start_time >= (now() - '1979:00:00'::interval)) AND (end_time < (now() - '405:00:00'::interval)))
        Filter: ((user_id = 'c8f0193b-cdc1-3f89-93db-2fc9698580bd'::uuid) AND (entity1 = '4bb9c1a0-ded7-3f16-93fb-bd2cbac9a815'::uuid))
        Buffers: shared hit=2 read=1595
        I/O Timings: read=743.997
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=258
Planning Time: 0.861 ms
Execution Time: 748.376 ms
```

The `Execution Time` ranges from `150ms` to `750ms`.

I assume these results are good, but I wonder if can improve them more.
As I see, most of the rows are read from the disk, I reach the partitions and I reach the index.
The I/O read time is the bottleneck here.

I measure the round trip on the query like that:

```python
now = time.time()
cur.execute(query)
finish = time.time() - now
print(finish)
```

Using `psycopg 3`.

The round trip is much larger than the `Execution Time`, and takes `1s`.

Moreover, I might run the same query without filtering on the timestamps.
Here's an analysis of this query:

```sql
Aggregate  (cost=7521.47..7521.48 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1021.549..1021.550 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared read=2186
  I/O Timings: read=1015.474
  ->  Index Scan using metrics_user_c8e1eb22_a_entity2_entity3_entity4_idx on metrics_user_c8e1eb22_a_entity1_4bb9c1a0_d metrics  (cost=0.56..7516.12 rows=2141 width=4) (actual time=2.341..1021.229 rows=2160 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((entity2 = '9311744c-3746-3502-84c9-d06e8b5ea2d6'::uuid) AND (entity3 = 'dbc6ad8f-311c-3794-ad2e-521f0e6684cc'::uuid) AND (entity4 = 'dbc6ad8f-311c-3794-ad2e-521f0e6684cc'::uuid))
        Filter: ((user_id = 'c8e1eb22-a627-3daa-884c-2205cf78d075'::uuid) AND (entity1 = '4bb9c1a0-ded7-3f16-93fb-bd2cbac9a815'::uuid))
        Buffers: shared read=2186
        I/O Timings: read=1015.474
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=243
Planning Time: 0.790 ms
Execution Time: 1021.618 ms
```

With a roundtrip time of `1.65s`.

Also here, I wonder if I can do better, and how.

So my questions are:

1. Can I do better in query speed (both of them)? If so, how?
2. Why the round trip takes so much longer?

Comment: Discussion on this question has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140158/discussion-on-question-by-igal-leikin-i-tried-to-optimize-my-pg-the-results-are).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can to to improve the speed of that query is to rewrite the table in index order:

```
CLUSTER metrics USING metrics_default_filters;
```

That should speed up the query considerably, because the rows will be concentrated in fewer buffers. Unfortunately, clustering has two disadvantages:

- while `CLUSTER` is running, you cannot access the table at all
- the order is not preserved, so you have to repeat `CLUSTER` every once in a while to keep the performance good

The only other way to speed this up is a) get faster disks or b) get enough RAM to cache the database in RAM.

Comment: When I try to cluster the data, I get `cannot cluster a partitioned table`. WDYT?

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming Postgres doesn’t have any weird behaviour when it comes to partitioning.

You’re running into a known hard problem: when you have a composite BTree index your filters can only be used to efficiently search the index if all the columns to the left of it have equality filters. This is due to the mechanics of the index.

This means that your `end_time` filter cannot be used to seek: you have to read every bit of the index that matches the other filters and you really need the additional filter to get good selectivity. We can see from the explain analyze that you’re having to read 1595 buffers and then throw away all rows but one.

There’s a few ways around this problem (I wouldn’t suggest playing around with clustering). The golden rule of indexing allows you to add further filters to `start_time` to improve the amount of data in the index that needs reading. Giving it a high end as well as a low end should help: you know for sure that the start time is before the end time (right?) so you can include an additional filter

```
AND start_time < now() - interval 'y hours'
```

This shrinks the range of data you need to read from the index and hopefully gets you over the finishing line.

For improving the no date filter query, you’ve already got an index which will give you data pretty quickly. It’s just going to be a lot of it. I would recommend paginating the response, sorting it by the `start_time` as the index will support that for you.